# Javascript Flyweight with WeakMap or WeakSet

Tags: javascript, weak-references, flyweight-pattern, weakmap

I want a Flyweight object so I created an Object and stored it's instances in a Map like this:

```
const FlyweightNumber = (function(){

    "use strict";

    const instances = new Map();

    class FlyweightNumber{

        constructor(number){

            Object.defineProperty(this, 'number', {
                value: number
            });

            if(!instances.get(number)){
                instances.set(number, this);
            }
            else {
                return instances.get(number);
            }

        }

        toString() {
            return this.number;
        }

        valueOf(){
            return this.number;
        }

        toJSON(){
            return this.number;
        }

    }

    return FlyweightNumber;

})();

module.exports = FlyweightNumber;
```

The problem is that when I'm not using a FlyweightNumber value anymore it is still in memory, stored in this Map.

Since WeakMap and WeakSet are supposed to let garbage colector clear it if it is not used anymore, how could I write a constructor to return the object in the WeakSet or WeakMap or create a new object if it is not stored anymore?

Comment: You can't. :/ ..

Comment: Don't overwrite the global `Number` function.

Comment: @Bergi hahahaha I wrote this as an example and forgot Number already exists. ....changed the example

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a [soft reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_reference) to implement your number cache. Unfortunately, JS doesn't have these.

And its `WeakMap` doesn't create weak references either, it's an [ephemeron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeron) actually. It does not allow you to observe whether an object has been collected.